# Is it possible to set Powershell profile code to run after every script?

Tags: scripting, powershell

I have set up a Powershell profile to run at Powershell startup.

Is it possible to configure powershell to call the profile after every .ps1 script so I don't have to call `.$profile` at the end of each script?

Comment: Why would you even want that? The profile is for startup intialization, not for dot-sourcing it randomly during a session. Depending on what you do in your profile you'd get plenty of errors anyway (I do, at least).

Comment: I use my profile for environment initialisation by cls-ing, changing to a directory with my saved scripts and a couple of lines of text to remind me of a few things.

Comment: I could write a set environment script that I call from profile initially, then get it call it again after a .ps1 script has been run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do what you're asking without hacking at PowerShell internals (not even sure then).  I would just do as you suggest, put this stuff in a separate script and then create a simple alias for it like `a` or `s` e.g.:

```
New-Alias s c:\users\john\bin\reset.ps1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put it in your `prompt` function to reload after every command:

```
function prompt
{
  . $profile
}
```

I don't know of any event you can hook into that would fire after a script is run.